# Django Rest Framework - Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "product-detail"

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm struggling with DRF. When I try to obtain a list of products using:

```
requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/").json()
```

Server error 500 occurs and an error is displayed as in the title: Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "product-detail"

However, when I try obtain a single product, request is successful:

`requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/t/").json()`

```
{'id': 1, 'url': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/t/', 'name': 't', 'slug': 't', 'description': '', 'order': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/orders/1/', 'ingredients': '', 'allergens': '', 'suggested_products': [], 'image': None, 'available': True, 'price': 100.0, 'category': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/categories/t/'}
```

So what's the problem here? I'm not using app namespacing, so this is not the cause. Slug field is used as lookup field instead of PK.
Serializer code:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField("product-detail",
                                               lookup_field="slug",
                                               read_only=True)

    category = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField("category-detail",
                                                   queryset=Category.objects.all(),
                                                   lookup_field="slug")
    image = Base64ImageField(max_length=settings.MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ("id", "url", "name", "slug", "description",
                  "order", "ingredients", "allergens", "suggested_products",
                  "image", "available", "price",
                  "category")
```

View code:

```
class ProductList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    lookup_field = "slug"

    @method_decorator(cache_page(LONG_CACHING_TIME))
    @method_decorator(vary_on_headers("Accept-Language"))
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(ProductList, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

class ProductDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    lookup_field = "slug"
```

Urlconf:

```
path("products/", ProductList.as_view(),
     name="product-list"),
path("products/<slug:slug>/", ProductDetail.as_view(),
     name="product-detail")
```

Thank you.

Edit:
Up until now, I couldn't fix that error. I concluded that the custom lookup field "slug" causes the problem, when default field "pk" is used, everything works as expected. But I strongly want to use that slug, really nobody encountered such a problem and can't share a solution?

Comment: It looks like posting `produts/` query will trigger url `products/...`. Can you post your version of Django/DRF? Have you try to remove leading slash from frist urls entry and requested url?